# how do i make a custom data source control return an ICollection data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ienumerable, paging, icollection

I have created a data source custom control wherein it inherits the DataSourceControl class and another class that inherits the DataSourceView class. The DataSourceView class has a method which overrides the ExecuteSelect method and returns an IEnumerable collection. I registered the assembly to my asp page and used it as my data source to a gridview. It works fine but whenever i include the attribute **AllowPaging="true"** to my gridview to limit the results shown i always get an error saying that

The data source  does not support server-side paging and it returned non-ICollection data

did i miss something? do i have another method to override to make it return an ICollection instead of an IEnumerable? i tried changing the ExecuteSelect method's return type to ICollection but then (of course) it gave me an error the the ExecuteSelect should have the correct return type (which is IEnumerable) to be able to be overriden.